# why in fragment, my keyboard no push view to top

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

Why in fragment when keyboard active, it doesn't push my `EditText` to the top of mykeyboard?

**In Activity**

[image: In Activity]

**In Fragment**

[image: In Fragment]

photo 1, it is in Activity. Keyboard push view to top
photo 2, it is in Fragment. Keyboard no push view!!

Answer (score 4):

add to your activity tag in manifest this:

> android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried and this is the result, it's not like Activity, It push all content to top

Answer (score 1):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/listChat"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</ListView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/chat_textbox"
        android:hint="comment"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/btnSend"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/send_button"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and my manifest

```
 <activity android:name=".ActivityHome" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I use it in Fragment